# Simple counter in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const MakeCount = () => {
 let [a, setA] = useState(0);
 setA(a++);
}
```

```js
const MainStack = ({ navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerTitle: () => false,
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home1' component={HomeScreen} options={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={24} color="black" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}/>
        ),
        headerRight: () => (
          <View style={styles.rIcon}>
            <AntDesign style={{paddingRight:10}} name="shoppingcart" size={24} color="black" />
            <MakeCount/> /**The problem*/
          </View>
        )
      }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Reviews1' component={ReviewsScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

So when I run this I get an error that says "Too many re-renders". I just want to create an incrementable text on my header where I cilck a button on another screen to increment it.
Is there any way to fix this or any suggestions?

### No button needed to increment for now, I just want the text to appear.

Comment: can you share an expo snack? couldnt understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@realfile/humiliated-ice-cream

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with setA(a++). The state should never be set in such a way that it can cause a re-render causing it to set state again (which is happening above). Simply put, setA increments the value of a, which causes setA to run again which again increments the value of a, and so on and so forth.

So, if you just want the state to be set only once, you can place it in a useEffect

```
useEffect(() => setA(a++), []);
```

But most of the time, you'd need to use buttons or stuff like that to update the state.